# Multiple custom DTOs to one model

Tags: java, json, spring, dto

I have a model with 10 fields and for optimization purposes, different REST service calls would either require or respond with a customized DTO (thus JSON) object.

For example: 
Car model has color, doors, automatic/manual, seats, owner, model, year

Service1 returns only model, year, and color

Service2 returns color, doors, automatic/manual, seats, model, year (notice owner is removed)

Please share the best practice (as I quite possibly is doing it wrong)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Comment: With the adapter pattern, the number of DTOs is not reduced right?  I guess I was wondering if others are managing DTOs differently.  I have seen some devs define their DTOs like CarOut, CarIn, CarUIIn, CarUIOut, ...etc.  Maintaining such DTOs seems really messy over time.

Comment: I don't think it's a bad idea to have many dtos for each case, but if you wanna reduce dto counts, you can use builder pattern. but if you make the dto immutable, you may have problem with jackson to transform data from dto to json..

Comment: Thanks to all for sharing, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to define different constructors for your model class.